# Display Settings on AC and Brightness key

Tags: display, laptop, lenovo, brightness, monitor

I have recently installed Xubuntu 14.02 on a Lenovo Thinkpad E555 I got everything working however I have had these problems:

1. When connecting AC power to the computer the Display Config comes up.
2. When adjusting brightness on the laptop Display Config appears.
3. When computer turns off the Display Config opens and thus turns on screen.

Can anyone help me with this?

Also running proprietary driver for the AMD GPU.